# How to get button value by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having issue by getting button value by ajax. 
I've got 4 buttons with other values

```
<button type="button" value="today" onclick=postdata class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Today</button>
<button type="button" onclick=postdata value="week"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Week</button>
<button type="button" value="month" onclick=postdata class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Today</button>
<button type="button" onclick=postdata value="year"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Week</button>



function postdata(link) {
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            date:$('button').val()
        }
    })
}
```

Onclick I always get value of first button , can somebody tell me how to get value of clicked button by ajax ?

Comment: Use ID instead of button. Also close your quotes for onclick events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `onclick=postada` to `onclick=postada(this)`

and then :

```
function postdata(link) {

$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        date:$(link).val();
    }
})
}
```

Notice : I don't recommend the way you're doing it , I prefer binding via :

`$('botton').on('....`

Comment: I'm having little problem now , i'm getting 404 error from ajax all the time and i don't know what is going on 
onclick looks like that: 
onclick="postdata(this);('{route r_name="send_date"}')"

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            date:val;
        }
    });
});
```

Btw, it's better to give your `button` a common class to target it more precisely.